# Simultaneous verbal arithmetic

Tags: word-problem

1. A B C D + A E F = E F G H and
2. I C J * E = A B C D

Each letter represents a unique digit from 0 to 9 and both equations must hold true.

Having some trouble solving this, here is what I have so far:

B + A = 10 or B + A > 10 since something must be carried over to the thousands column (A) in equation 1

I also know that A + 1 = E since the 1 is carried over

17 >= B + A >= 10

A cannot equal 0,9

Any idea how to solve this?
Any contributions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You also know that $E = A + 1$, because the carried digit must have been a $1$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yeah sorry, forgot to add that to my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A quick computer search finds the unique answer:

$A, B, \dots, J = 6, 5, 3, 8, 7, 2, 1, 0, 9, 4$.

Hence there is not much to explain. Without any context, I cannot tell whether it is intended to solve it by computer or without computer.

Comment: without a computer preferably

Comment: No idea for the moment. Sometimes these puzzles are even generated with the help of computers in the first place, so I'm not really willing to spend time thinking about a no-computer solution...

Comment: I wrote a program to go through all possibilities of $I, C, J, E$. This then determines $A, B, C, D$. I then go through remaining possibilities of $F$, which determines $G$ and $H$.

Comment: It was in C, and I already deleted it... It's not that tricky and you may write it yourself, with Python or any of your preferred programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's doable by hand. At least, I did it (with a couple of sheets of paper...)

We know that `A + 1 = E`. Look now at `xCJ * E = xxCD` and search for all the possible combinations for `(A) CJED`: they are

```
A C J E D 
1 9 7 2 4
1 9 8 2 6
2 4 7 3 1 
2 4 9 3 7 
2 9 7 3 1
2 9 8 3 4 
3 6 7 4 8 
3 9 8 4 2 
5 3 9 6 4
5 7 9 6 4 
6 3 4 7 8
6 8 3 7 1
```

Moreover, from the multiplication we have a range of the possible values of `I`:

```
A E  I
1 2 5-9
2 3 6-9
3 4 7-9
5 6 8-9
6 7 8-9
```

Putting all together and completing the multiplication, we have

```
A C J E D I B
1 9 7 2 4 6 3
1 9 8 2 6 7 5
2 4 7 3 1 8 5
2 4 7 3 1 9 8
2 4 9 3 7 8 5
2 9 7 3 1 6 0
2 9 7 3 1 8 6
2 9 8 3 4 6 0
3 9 8 4 2 7 1
5 3 9 6 4 8 0
5 7 9 6 4 8 2
6 3 4 7 8 9 5
```

From here, considering `D + F = (1)H` we remain with

```
A B C D E F G H I J
1 5 9 6 2 4   0 7 8
2 0 9 1 3 4   5 6 7
2 6 9 1 3 4   5 8 7
2 0 9 4 3 1   5 6 8
6 5 3 8 7 2   0 9 4
```

and only the last line (with `G = 1`) satisfies the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Putting this up. If anyone has partial insights, feel free to add to this post instead of commenting (since writing `as is` text is difficult in the comments).

So far, we have

```
  A    B  C    D
+      A (A+1) F
--------------
 (A+1) F  G    H

   I  C  J
x       (A+1)
-----------
A  B  C  D
```